# Why am I not able to call the same activity via adb for my application multiple times?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adb

When using `adb` to execute a shell to an activity the activity will be called in the application.  If I try to execute the same adb command to the same activity it will not function correctly.  I have to use am force-stop before I can call the same activity again.

```
 adb shell am start -n com.xxx.android/.SomeActivity
 adb shell am start -n com.xxx.android/.SomeActivity
```

This particular activity will write out to a log.

**Question**

What is the correct way to execute an activity more than one time from adb?

After reading this I'm wondering if am start is not the right command to be using if we have already started up the application?

How would I make adb calls to my activities after the application is already running, IE I have ran `am start`

Thank you

Sample Activity

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("SomeActivity", "Starting Activity" );
        ... does something
        Log.i("SomeActivity", "Finished" );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "make a call" mean? What does it mean to "call" an activity? What exactly does "the log being updated with another call" mean? Your `adb shell` command starts an activity.

Comment: Updated I think that should be more clear.  After reading it again I'm thinking we may not be calling adb correctly for the second attempt since its using am start again.  I think we should probably be using a different adb call once the application has been started.

Comment: "If I try to execute the same adb command to the same activity it will not function correctly." What do you expect to happen when you request an activity to start multiple times? What does "function correctly" mean?

Comment: Why do you need another activity to make the logging calls that you talked about in your original question? Can another regular Java class do the logging without the overhead of starting an activity?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  It will not run the activity which logs out to logcat.  I just chose that as an example.  The activity is preforming something, when it finishes we log to logcat.  The problem I see is that if I call the same activity twice I do not see its output twice.

Comment: We need to back up a bit. When you say "it will not run the activity", which methods are you referring to? The activity's callback methods will be called according to the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Even more importantly, why do you need to start another activity for the logging? Is there a reason you don't do this with a non-activity class?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  I will take some time tomorrow to further look into this.  I had taken over this area from another developer (I am not an Android developer) and wanted to know what was happening.  From the discussions and comments above it sounds like their may be another approach which is more applicable.  I'm not sure why this was down voted so much...

Comment: The down votes were probably because your original question was not very clear. Also your edit removed some relevant information.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I adjusted my original question within the first 5 minutes of posting to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to start an Activity which is already running, the Android system does not create a new instance of the Activity. Instead, it just brings the existing one to the foreground.

This means that the Activity's lifecycle callback methods will be called as appropriate. You should read [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) to get a better understanding of these methods. In particular, I think you expect `onCreate()` to be called the second time you try to start the activity. This is not guaranteed.

Comment: Does it rerun what that activity does?

Comment: @ALM The activity life cycle methods will be called as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understanding your question you might need to send an intent your activity.
if you want to send an action to your activity then you can use -a

In your case you want -a to specify the action, -d to specify the data URI, and --ez to specify the extra (if needed).
You can find the action name by looking up Intent.ACTION_VIEW in the documentation.

this example is with an extra Boolean

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d com.package.activity:// --ez parameterName true
```

this would be an equvilant to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("com.package.activity://"));
intent.putExtra("parameterName", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in your activity you can catch it through onNewIntent or in onCreate

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec